# unable to add qrcode grails plugin?

Tags: grails, plugins, qr-code, grails-2.2

I started a brand new grails 2.2 app. I want to add qrcode plugin.

https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/technipelago/qrcode

the documentation says for grails 2 app use

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  // ...
  plugins {
    compile ':qrcode:0.7'
    // ...
  }
}
```

here is my buildconfig after adding qrcode plugin

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

// uncomment (and adjust settings) to fork the JVM to isolate classpaths
//grails.project.fork = [
//   run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256]
//]

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'
    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.2.1"


        compile ':cache:1.0.1'
        compile ':qrcode:0.7'

    }
}
```

when i build

it says

```
|Loading Grails 2.2.0
|Configuring classpath
Error |
Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:qrcode:0.7
```

I appreciate any help as to integrating qrcode plugin. I dont need latest version. I just need to make qrcode plugin to work. Old version will do.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First add local maven repo `(mavenLocal())` to your in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
repositories {
    inherits true
    grailsPlugins()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    }
```

Then add dependency in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
dependencies {
        compile "org.grails.plugins:qrcode:0.7"
      }
```

If by adding in dependency not work then add it to plugins:

```
plugins {
  compile(':qrcode:0.7')
}
```

You can refer [repo](https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/qrcode/) of this plugin where you can see available versions.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for the response but the documentation says "For Grails 2 use version 0.7, for Grails 3 use version 0.8+.". I can only use 0.7 since the version i am using is grails 2.2.

Comment: ok i changed to 0.8 and same problem. can you take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51147163/how-to-add-maven-plugin-to-grails-2-2-app?

Comment: @kofhearts Answer updated, Please let me know is it working or not

Comment: sorry tried both and still says failed to resolve dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try version 0.7.1

I looks
It is also for Grails 2.x and should load just fine by putting it in the `plugins {}` section like you did.