# How to add maven plugin to grails 2.2 app?

Tags: maven, grails, plugins, grails-2.2

I want to add the following barcode plugin to my grails 2.2 app.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core/3.3.0

I have tried

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
```

I have also tried

```
'com.google.zxing:core:jar:3.3.0'
```

but it doesn't resolve dependency.

It says

```
Error |
Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0
```

Here is the full BuildConfig file

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

// uncomment (and adjust settings) to fork the JVM to isolate classpaths
//grails.project.fork = [
//   run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256]
//]

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }


    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'
    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.2.1"


        compile ':cache:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'

    }
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't a plugin , it's a library

You must to move your compile directive to the `dependencies` closure